# Asked to enter values for variables set in terraform module using terragrunt

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I have a terragrunt project with the following structure:

```
|---terraform.tfvars
|---account
|   |---us-east-1
|       |---nonprod
|           |---s3
|               |---terraform.tfvars
|---modules
|   |---s3
|       |---main.tf
|---source
    |---s3
        |---main.tf
        |---provider.tf
        |---vars.tf
```

/account/us-east-1/nonprod/s3/terraform.tvars

```
terragrunt = {
  terraform {
    source = "../../../../modules/s3"
  }

  include {
    path = "${find_in_parent_folders()}"
  }
}
```

/modules/s3/main.tf

```
module "s3" {
    source = "../../source/s3"

    app-name = "example-app"
    aws-region = "us-east-1"
    bucket-name = "example-app-bucket"
}
```

/source/s3/main.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  region        = "${var.aws-region}"
  bucket        = "${var.bucket-name}"
  acl           = "private"
  force_destroy = "true"

  tags {
    Name        = "${var.app-name}"
  }
}
```

When I run terragrunt from the `account` directory:

```
$ terragrunt plan-all --terragrunt-source ../../../../source
```

I am asked to enter values for the variables I have set in /modules/s3/main.tf

```
var.app-name
  Enter a value:
```

However, when I run `terraform plan` from the `modules/s3` directory, it seems to work.

What is wrong with this setup when using terragrunt?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the confusion that leads to the problem is in the naming of things. i.e. `source/s3` is really the TF *module*, while `modules/s3` is the TF code that is *calling (using)* the module.

`terragrunt` expects to find the module source in the config, not the TF code that calls the module.

Try this in `terraform.tfvars`:

```
terragrunt = {
  terraform {
    source = "../../../../source/s3"
  }

  # ... other code & configs ...

}
```

HTH!